# What is the dataset return from dataframe.stack()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to work on dataframe which i have used .stack() function

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', usecols =['firstround','secondround','thirdround','fourthround','fifthround'])

sortedArray = df.stack().value_counts()

sortedArray = sortedArray.sort_index()
```

I need to retrieve the first index column values and the 2nd index column values from the sortedArray, meaning i need x and y value from the sorted array.

Any idea how i can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html), because output from `stack` is `Series`:

```
x = sortedArray.iloc[0] 
y = sortedArray.iloc[1]
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','a','s'],
                   'B':['a','s','a'],
                   'C':['s','d','a']})

print (df)
   A  B  C
0  a  a  s
1  a  s  d
2  s  a  a
```

```
sortedArray = df.stack().value_counts()
print (sortedArray)
a    5
s    3
d    1
dtype: int64

sortedArray = sortedArray.sort_index()
print (sortedArray)
a    5
d    1
s    3
dtype: int64

x = sortedArray.iloc[0] 
y = sortedArray.iloc[1] 

print (x)
5
print (y)
1

print (sortedArray.tolist())
[5, 1, 3]

print (sortedArray.index.tolist())
['a', 'd', 's']
```

Comment: how do i retrieve an array of index and an array of the sorted iloc array though?

Comment: Do you think `x = sortedArray.iloc[:2].values` and `x = sortedArray.index[:2]` ?

Comment: oh i mean like i need an array of (x) [a,d,s] and another array of (y) [5,1,3]

Comment: Do you think list? add `sortedArray.tolist()` and `sortedArray.index.tolist()`